# Upgrading a Symfony project from version 2 to version 3

Tags: symfony

I have a project running using Symfony version 2 and I wanted to migrate this same project to Symfony version 3. Anybody knows how to do that, I will be very grateful cause right now I'm stuck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to other major version is described in Symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/upgrade_major.html

Comment: And link only answers are strongly discouraged on stackoverflow.  Consider providing a detailed list of instructions.